# Python checking sql database column for value

Tags: python, database, sqlite

How would one check an entire column in sqlite database for a given value and if found set a variable to true

something like

```
hasvalue = 'false'

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT id FROM column WHERE hasvalue = '1' LIMIT 1;")
***IF execute returned rows set hasvalue = true here***

if hasvalue == 'true':
   do something
else:
   dosomethingelse
```

How would I make hasvalue turn to true if the sql query returned with something and if it returned 0 rows stay false?

Basically I want to execute something ONLY if something in a column equals 1

Comment: So You want do it with python or do it with SQL coz good SQL-QUerry can do it too.

Comment: python as I want to execute some code only if the database returns true for my search

Comment: So Make an proper SQL like :
'SELECT 1 FROM <your_table_name> WHERE <column_name>=<your value> ;' 
Now just use **fetch** and if there will be zero rows with this value You will get NULL back, and 1 otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little confused by your question. The SQL query suggests that you are using a *table* named `column`? If I can ignore that and assume you have a table named `test` which has columns `id` (an int) and `name` (a string). Then the query:

```
SELECT id FROM test where name = 'something'
```

would select all rows that have `name` set to the string `'something'`.

In Python this would be:

```
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT id FROM test where name = 'something' LIMIT 1")

if cur.fetchone():
    do_something()
else:
    do_something_else()
```

The key here is to use [`cursor.fetchone()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone) which will try and retrieve a row from the cursor. If there are no rows `fetchone()` will return `None`, and `None` evaluates to `False` when used as a condition in an `if` statement.

You could create a function to generalise:

```
def has_value(cursor, table, column, value):
    query = 'SELECT 1 from {} WHERE {} = ? LIMIT 1'.format(table, column)
    return cursor.execute(query, (value,)).fetchone() is not None

if has_value(cur, 'test', 'name', 'Ranga'):
    do_something()
else:
    do_something_else()
```

This code constructs a query for the given table, column, and value and returns `True` if there is at least one row with the required value, otherwise it returns `False`.

Comment: if not cur.fetchone() is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you very much for the detailed explanation!